# Recursive program in Java

Tags: java, string, recursion

I have a program that realizes this:

```
Input: "(-123)+(200)" -> String
Output: 77 -> Int

Input: "((-123)+(200))*((2)+(1))"
Output: 231
```

Well, I have the code, but I don't know if it's a good idea to use regular expressions. The teachers gave me a function that separates the String, for example:

```
int n = StringUtils.exprMainOperator ("(-123)+(200)");
n = 7;
```

My idea is to separate, by 'n' each String, in a substring, but I don't know how to realize this recursively. Any idea? Not in code please, so I can learn, thanks.

Comment: what does StringUtils.exprMainOperator returns, if no operator exists like for "123"

Comment: return string.length();  is in this case 3;

Comment: does `StringUtils.exprMainOperator` take into account parenthesis and priority of operations?

Comment: Yes, for example this String int n = StringUtils....((-123)+(200))*((2)+(2)); n = 14, this method separate the expression in equivalent parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways of implementing it, this is some pseudocode that would work. I am assuming that you only have arithmetic operators, and that `StringUtils.exprMainOperator` handles parenthesis/priority of operations:

```
public static int evaluateExpression(String exp) {
    if(exp.charAt(0) == '(' && exp.charAt(exp.length()-1) == ')' 
        && /*These two parenthesis correspond to each other*/) return evaluateExpression(exp.substring(1, exp.length()-1));

    if(/*is Valid Number*/) return Integer.parseInt(exp);

    int n = StringUtils.exprMainOperator(exp);
    char op = exp.charAt(n);
    String preop = exp.substring(0, n), postop = exp.substring(n+1);

    if(op == '+') return evaluateExpression(preop) + evaluateExpression(postop);
    if(op == '-') return evaluateExpression(preop) - evaluateExpression(postop);
    if(op == '*') return evaluateExpression(preop) * evaluateExpression(postop);
    if(op == '/') return evaluateExpression(preop) / evaluateExpression(postop);

    //You shouldn't reach this part of the code
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I have a question, I have the error: missin return statment, but I don't know that I have return...?

Comment: you have to add a `return` statement at the end of the method, because the compiler sees that all `return` statement are inside `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Here are the imports you need
 import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
 import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
 import javax.script.ScriptException;

public static void main (String args [])
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    in = /*your input*/;
    System.out.println(StringEngineCalc(in));
}
public static String StringEngineCalc(String yourString) {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    String calc= "";
    try {
        calc = engine.eval(message).toString();
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        System.out.println("Error al realizar el cálculo.");
    }
    return calc;
}
```

Here you are a class that gives you back a String (if you want a String, if not just remove the "toString" and change the public static string for public static int) with the calc.

It uses javascript to solve mathematic problems and its like the easiest way to make a calculator :)