# convert String containing a arithmetic sign into a integer value

Tags: java, string

```
    String a = "a*3";
    a = a.replace("a","45");

    // a contains 45*3
```

How do you I convert that to a DOUBLE which outputs 135.00 ??

Note : a can have any arthimetic operation... ( + , - , /)

Comment: Does it have one operator at most?

Comment: a can have multiple operators... like a = "((a+3)*4)"

Comment: If division is a valid operation in this string, there's no guarantee the result will be an int. (Just putting that out there)

Comment: my bad. I changed INT to double

Comment: You can check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form

Comment: Go see my answer to this post, it's essentially the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35984375/recursive-program-in-java/35984815#35984815

Comment: There is a library called exp4j i.e. expression4j which has predefined method like python `eval` function. Check this out http://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest solution is to pass this off to Java's built in JavaScript engine.

```
public class Eval {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByExtension("js");

        engine.put("a", 45);
        Number val = (Number) engine.eval("a*3");
        System.out.println(val.doubleValue());
    }
}
```